# How set the Bibliography to the tmp folder using vim latex?

Tags: bibliographies, vim-latex

I want to a add the bibliography in to my beamer document.

Consider the tree

```
├── reference.bib
├── slides.pdf
├── slides.tex
└── tmp
    ├── slides.aux
    ├── slides.log
    ├── slides.nav
    ├── slides.out
    ├── slides.pdf
    ├── slides.snm
    └── slides.toc
```

with  `reference.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{Vickrey1961,
AUTHOR = {W. Vickrey},
TITLE = {Counterspeculation, auctions and sealed tenders},
}
```

and `slides.tex`

```
\begin{document}
    Bla Bla \cite{Vickrey1961}.
   \bibliographystyle{plain}
   \bibliography{reference}
\end{document}
```

In my `vimrc` i have the line

```
 let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'mkdir -p tmp; pdflatex -output-directory tmp -interaction=nonstopmode $*; cp tmp/*.pdf .'
```

which keeps my folder clean from all the other files however there seems to be problem when I want to build the bibliography.

I get the message

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Vickrey1961' on page 10 undefined on input line 155.

[10]
No file slides.bbl.
(tmp/slides.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

How can is the compile command `\ll` so that all bibliography is referenced correctly?

Comment: After the first `pdflatex` run, you should execute `biber $*` to create the missing `bbl` file and afterwards `pdflatex` again (maybe two times).

Comment: Could you confirm two things: Does this work if you manually execute the commands (`-output-directory tmp` may need an `=`)? What is `g:Tex_DefaultTargetFormat`?

Answer (score 2):

The LaTeX build wrapper [ltx2any](https://github.com/akerbos/ltx2any) may be a solution. This automatically copies all required files to your tmp folder and the results back to your main folder. Normally is used a temporary folder, if you want to use a folder in your directory, you can specify it with

```
ltx2any -t ./tmp filename.tex
```

For more options, see `ltx2any --help`.